# Assigning negative value to char

Tags: c++, c

Why does the following code print "?" ? 
Also how can -1 be assigned to an `unsigned char`?

```
char test;
unsigned char testu; //isn't it supposed to hold values in range 0 - 255?
test = -1;
testu = -1;
cout<<"TEST CHAR = "<<test<<endl;
cout<<"TESTU CHAR = "<<testu<<endl;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`unsigned` simply affects how the internal representation of the number (`char`s are numbers, remember) is interpreted. So `-1` is `1111 1111` in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) notation, which when put into an `unsigned char` changes the meaning (for the same bit representation) to 255.

The question mark is probably the result of your font/codepage not mapping the (extended) ASCII value 255 to a character it can display.

I don't think `<<` discerns between an unsigned char and a signed char, since it interprets their values as ASCII codes, not plain numbers.

Also, it [depends on your compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/21475) whether `char`s are signed or unsigned by default; actually, the spec states there's [three different char types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436513/char-signed-char-char-unsigned-char/436561#436561) (plain, signed, and unsigned).

Comment: `char` will behave like either `signed char` or like `unsigned char`, at the implementation's discretion, but is a separate type from whichever one it behaves like. Yes, this is exactly as much of a backwards-compatibility keep-everyone-happy hack (that actually probably causes problems for lots of people anyway) as it sounds like.

Answer (score 4):

When you assign a negative value to an unsigned variable, the result is that it wraps around.  -1 becomes 255 in this case.

Comment: Correct.  Conversion of an integer to an unsigned type wraps around modulo 1 greater than the maximum value of the unsigned type.  For a typical system with 8-bit bytes, it's reduced modulo 256 (UCHAR_MAX+1).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know C or C++, but my intuition is telling me that it's wrapping -1 to 255 and printing `ÿ`, but since that's not in the first 128 characters it prints `?` instead. Just a guess.

To test this, try assigning `-191` and see if it prints `A` (or `B` if my math is off).

Comment: What it prints depends on the locale.  `ÿ` is character 255 in Unicode or Latin-1, but in UTF-8, for example, it has a multi-byte representation.

Answer (score 1):

Signed/unsigned is defined by the use of the highest order bit of that number.
You can assign a negative integer to it. The sign bit will be interpreted in the signed case (when you perform arithmetics with it). When you treat it it like a character it will simply take the highest order bit as if it was an unsigned char and just produce an ASCII char beyond 127 (decimal):

```
unsigned char c = -2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
unsigned char c = 128;
```

WHEN the c is treated as a character.
-1 is an exception: it has all 8 bits set and is treated as 255 dec.

Comment: I think -2 is equal to 254