# Arguments of Boost's TCP basic_resolver_query constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm having some trouble when putting a very simple c++ program to listen to a given port. Mainly, I have problems when creating a basic_resolver_query. If I do it like this:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( "0.0.0.0", "5938" );
```

i works flawlessly. But obviously I don't want to hardcode the port, so I've been trying to read it from a file an passing it there: it isn't working.

If I try to pass it directly as `std::string`, it doesn't work, with I guess was to be expected. But I've tried passing `m_listenPort.c_string()` and it doesn't do it.

I've been trying to look in the documentation, and in examples, but I can find nothing. How do I have to do it?

Comment: `c_string()` doesn't exist as a member of std::string, its `c_str()`

Comment: please clarify what *doesn't work* means, we are not mind readers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can tell, `boost::asio::ip::basic_resolver_query` has been constructable with two `std::string` arguments since Boost.Asio was introduced.  Here is the overloaded constructor documentation in [1.35](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query/overload3.html) and [1.53](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_resolver_query/basic_resolver_query/overload3.html).

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main()
{
  std::string host = "127.0.0.1";
  std::string port = "1234";
  using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
  tcp::resolver::query query1("127.0.0.1", "1234");
  tcp::resolver::query query2(host, port);
  tcp::resolver::query query3(host.c_str(), port.c_str());
}
```

Is it possible that you are not using `std::string` or a type that provides a user-defined conversion to a type from which `std::string` can be constructed?  For instance, `std::string` provides `c_str()`, not `c_string()`.  Additionally, it is constructable via `const char*`, not `const unsigned char*` or `const signed char*`, as the three types are distinct.

Comment: Interesting, there indeed are 3 char types (signed, unsigned and plain): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436513/char-signed-char-char-unsigned-char

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:

```
std::string host = "192.168.1.1", port = "1234";
tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), host, port);
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had some problems when trying to use an IP address instead of a URL.  Discovered the technique of creating an endpoint and using it in the connect method on the next_layer object off of the  socket object works for me:

```
const boost::asio::ip::address IP(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(serverPath));
int iport = atoi(port.c_str());
const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint EP(IP, iport);
// Set up an SSL context.
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(*IOService, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1_client);
// Specify to not verify the server certificiate right now.
ctx.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);
// Init the socket object used to initially communicate with the server.
pSocket = new boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(*IOService, ctx);
//
// Try to connect to the server.  Note - add timeout logic at some point.
boost::system::error_code EC;
pSocket->next_layer().connect(EP, EC);
if (EC)
{
   // Log an error.  This worker thread should exit gracefully after this.
   stringstream ss;
   ss << "SSLSocket::Connect: connect failed to " << sClientIp << " : " << uiClientPort << ".  Error: " << EC.message() + ".\n";
   Log.LogString(ss.str(), LogError);
}
```