# Implementation of fixed width integer types std::uint8_t and std::int8_t, C++

Tags: c++, c++11, integer

I'm using the *fixed width integer types* `std::int8_t` and `std::uint8_t` which are included in C++ since C++11 (header `<cstdint>`). I use the gcc compiler for c++ programming (Linux, gcc --version 4.8.2).

On my machine  the lines

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

//...

std::cout << std::is_same<std::uint8_t,unsigned char>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_same<std::int8_t,char>::value << std::endl;
```

give the output

```
1
0
```

In other words: `std::uint8_t` is implemented as `unsigned char` but `std::int8_t` *is not* implemented as `char`! I have no (reasonable) idea how it could be that `std::int8_t` is not implemented as `char`. Question: How can this result be interpreted?

Comment: Try `std::is_same<std::int8_t, signed char>`.

Comment: `char` can be signed on some systems. Try comparing with `signed char` instead.

Comment: @ Matteo Italia + 0x499602D2: For signed char it gives 1, you are right. Is the difference between char and signed char only formal?

Comment: @sperber: Why do you say that? Sounds like you think `char` is always signed, but that is not true. 1) It can be changed by compiler flags; 2) it's not even necessarily signed _by default_ on all systems. The signedness of `char` is entirely implementation-defined.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Thanks, I didn't know it was implementation defined and indeed believed it was required to be signed.

Comment: @sperber: Okay then yeah it would be silly ;P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably they used `signed char`, which is sensible since compiler options (in gcc `-fsigned-char` and `-funsigned-char`) can change the signedness of plain `char`.

Notice that [`char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are guaranteed to be distinct types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436561/214671), so it's normal that, even if on your compiler `char` is signed, it isn't considered the same as `signed char`.

> Is the difference between char and signed char only formal?

No; `char` can be signed or unsigned depending on compiler and compiler options; `signed char` is always signed, no matter what.

(now, if you ask me, plain `char` should always be `unsigned`, but that's just my opinion)

Comment: _"plain char should always be unsigned"_ What would be the point in that? That's what `unsigned char` is for...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: because having a `signed` char by default (in most compilers) is only an annoyance - both when dealing with text *and* when dealing with "raw bytes" you *never* want to see signed values (= negative numbers for bytes >127); `unsigned char` is annoyingly long to type (especially when you are casting void pointers on the fly) and does not allow constructor-style casts. Also, in the rare cases when you actually want `signed char` you have to ask for it explicitly anyway. I don't know, the whole implementation-defined signedness seems to me gratuitous stupidity.

Comment: Considering that char is a number just like int is, sign should be given with the same rule as int: what about `int` `signed int` `unsigned int`? The sam shold be for `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`. But there are inconsistencies...

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: IMO for practical usage `unsigned char` is needed way more often than `signed char`, but OK, that too would be better than the current state of affairs, at least in the rare occasions when you need a `signed char` you wouldn't have to specify `signed` explicitly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: yes, that was exactly my point: make evident a spec. inconsistency.

Answer (score 4):

The type `char` is not required to be signed, even though on many systems it is.
Even when that is the case, [it is distinct from the type `signed char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436561/214671).

**It is likely that `int8_t` is an alias for `signed char`.**

Answer (score 0):

char is not always signed, like many other inconsistencies that happen between various CPP implementations. I only realized this when I moved from MingGw on codeblocks to my simple phone compiler, which uses unsigned --- char.

Another inconsistency is void pointer and operator++. MingGw defines a one byte increment for that operator. But most other compilers won't compile incrementation of void pointers.

Then there is endianness.

Furthermore each compiler has its own preprocessor which uses different attributes and stuff.

These inconsistencies make programming in C and CPP quite difficult as undefined behaviour can cause crashes and logic errors that can be very hard to find.

A language like Java is very comfortable to use because Java compilers are made by one source, Oracle, and it is a write once kind of language.

However, it is not CPP fault that why inconsistencies are in the language. CPP and C stick to a low level approach, and each processor, each hardware is made differently. CPP takes these things into account.

Trying to write general code for the hardware is going to produce code that will be slower.