# Implicit conversion from uint8_t to int gone wrong, when explicit one gone well

Tags: c++, type-conversion, long-integer, implicit-conversion, uint8t

I've got a program, which gets numbers n(quantity of blocks) and r(volume), and after it gets n sizes in format `firstsize secondsize thirdsize` (e.g. `1 1 1`) so the overall simplest input is:
`1 1 1 1 1` which in theory should return 1. But it doesn't.

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Size{
    long long w=0,h=0,d=0;
};
istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Size& rval){
    istr >> rval.w >> rval.h >> rval.d;
    return istr;
}


long long calcMass(Size s, int r){
    long long res = s.d*s.h*s.w*r;

    cout << "Gained:" << res << '\n';
    cout << "Got: sizes:{" << s.d << ' ' << s.h << ' ' << s.w << "}, p = " << r << '\n';
    return res;
}


int main(){
    int n;
    long long sum = 0;

    Size s;
    uint8_t r; // Condition is that r<100

    cin >> n >> r;

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> s;
        sum += calcMass(s,r);
    }
    cout << sum;

}
```

*Actually*, I got this problem solved by changing type of the `r` variable in `main()` from `uint8_t` to `int`, but the problem is, I don't understand why it didn't work whilst being `uint8_t`. When I try the following code:

```
    cout <<'\n' << static_cast<long long>(static_cast<int>((static_cast<uint8_t>(1))));
```

It gives me 1.

So, I decided to inspect the situation with `uint8_t r` in `main()`. `uint8_t r = 1` in `main()` somehow becomes the `int r = 49` in `calcMass()` and I do not undertand why.

I know about the rules of implicit conversion, that before the operation variables smaller in size than `int` are converted to `int`, and then the "smaller in size" variable is converted to bigger one (e.g. `int r` to `long long` in `calcMass(Size,int)` function?), but I do not understand the thing: why do `uint8_t r = 1` becomes `int r = 49`?

Also, I tried changing the type of `r` in `calcMass()` from `int` to `uint8_t`. As supposed, `uint8_t r = 1` in `main()` becomes `uint8_t r = 1` in `calcMass()`, but the result of this function is still `49`!

These I used to run the program:

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
System Type: 64bit
C++ compiler: MinGW
```

I would be pleased if somebody could explain *why* explicit conversion of `uint8_t` to `long long` isn't equal to the imlpicit one when passing it to `calcMass()` and doing operations with `long long` using it.

Comment: 49 is ASCII code of '1'. So look in the direction of unsigned char to understand why you get 49.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, OP suspected implicit vs. explicit conversion issues but that's not the reason. Instead, the `stream` I/O operators have to be investigated.

Elaborating the [comment of S.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58669085/implicit-conversion-from-uint8-t-to-int-gone-wrong-when-explicit-one-gone-well/58669388#comment103640431_58669085):

> 49 is ASCII code of '1'. So look in the direction of unsigned char to understand why you get 49.

The `std::stream` operators work a little bit different for `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` ([operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), [operator>>(std::basic_istream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2)) than for the other integral types ([std::basic_ostream::operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), [std::basic_istream::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)).

That's for input as well as for output.

`std::cout << (int)49;` prints `49` but `std::cout << (char)49;` prints `1`.

`std::uint8_t` is very likely a `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;`.
([SO: Implementation of fixed width integer types std::uint8_t and std::int8_t, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25230355/7478597))

Sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "(int)49: " << (int)49 << "\n";
  std::cout << "(char)49: " << (char)49 << "\n";
  std::cout << "(std::uint8_t)49: " << (std::uint8_t)49 << "\n";
  int i; char c; std::uint8_t u8;
  std::istringstream in("49\n1\n1");
  in >> i >> c >> u8;
  std::cout << "i: " << i << '\n';
  std::cout << "(int)c: " << (int)c << '\n';
  std::cout << "(int)u8: " << (int)u8 << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
(int)49: 49
(char)49: 1
(std::uint8_t)49: 1
i: 49
(int)c: 49
(int)u8: 49
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ad3f4c9f22b6828)