# Why doesn't C++ accept signed or unsigned char for arrays of characters

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am using C++ in native mode with Visual Studio 2017.  That compiler compiles the statement below without complaint:

```
const char * AnArrayOfStrings[]  = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
```

However, if I change the above statement to specify that char is signed or unsigned, the compiler emits a **C2440** error.  For instance, the statements below, do **not** compile:

```
const signed   char * AnArrayOfStrings2[] = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};

const unsigned char * AnArrayOfStrings2[] = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
```

I fail to see the reason for the compiler refusing to compile the statement when the sign of char is made explicit.

**My question is:** is there a good reason that I have failed to see for the compiler refusing to compile those statements ?

Thank you for your help (I did research in StackOverflow, the C++ documentation, I used Google and, consulted about a dozen C/C++ books in an effort to find the answer myself but, a reason still eludes me.)

Comment: Fyi, [you may find this interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436513/char-signed-char-char-unsigned-char).

Comment: fyi, with `gcc` and `clang` I get a bunch of warnings about this, with `g++` and `clang++` I get a bunch of errors.

Comment: Remember that `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three distinct types not just 3 variations of the same type.

Comment: @WhozCraig: yes, it was interesting.  It's one of the posts I read before asking the question.  It's obvious why signed char and unsigned char are different types. They will be used differently.  What's a mystery to me is why a third "type", neither signed nor unsigned is necessary, what is gained/avoided, if anything by the "plain type" ?.  It seems to only cause problems without solving any.

Comment: Your question is purely about C++ language which is totally separate language than C. And C/C++ does not exist. It's either C or C++. If a book really uses "C/C++" in the title, you should probably dump it immediately. Please do not spam with adding unrelated language tags.

Comment: @Gerhardh: it certainly isn't my intention to spam.  I included the C tag because most C programmers are using C++ compilers and will be affected by the C++ compiler behavior.

Comment: Really? I don't know any C programmer using a C++ compiler. If you use a compiler in C mode, it is no longer a C++ compiler. If you use a C++ compiler the laws of C++ apply, and you are programming C++.

Comment: @Gerhardh: the fact that you don't know any doesn't mean there aren't any.  I know a number of them.

Comment: Neither does the fact that you know a number of them make them "most of them". And strictly speaking, as soon as you use a C++ compiler you must use C++ language rules. Try `char *new = malloc (100);` in a C++ compiler. If you use C++ language rules with a C++ compiler, you are typically not called a C programmer any longer.

Comment: @Ajay Brahmakshatriya: often, "good" C programmers take advantage of the stricter type checking afforded by C++. Avoiding bugs is one of the characteristics of good programmers regardless of language used.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur: Things will make a hell of a lot more sense if you realize that this is just a matter of awful naming, and the character types have nothing to do with the integer types: `signed char` is a signed *byte*, and `unsigned char` is an unsigned *byte*, `char` is a narrow *"character"*, `wchar_t` is a wide *"character"*.

Comment: It is true that many well-written C programs are also valid C++ programs and can be compiled with a C++ compiler. The danger lies in C programs that are also valid C++ programs *but silently have different semantics*. It is therefore necessary to rigorously approach these languages as fully separate and distinct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`"z1y2x3w4"` is `const char[9]` and there is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `const signed char*`.

You could use `reinterpret_cast`

```
const signed char * AnArrayOfStrings[]  = {reinterpret_cast<const signed char *>("z1y2x3w4"),
                                           reinterpret_cast<const signed char *>("Aname")};
```

Comment: "`"z1y2x3w4"` is `const char *`" actually, it's a `const char[9]`.

Comment: What troubles me the most is that, whether a char is signed or unsigned, it still uses the same amount of space in memory which is the first thing the compiler needs to know.  Whether the char is signed or unsigned depends on how the programmer wishes to interpret it and based on the intended interpretation, the compiler can decide if later statements are valid or not.  The compiler should be "happy" that I'm telling it how I'm going to use/view the characters.  I don't see that a "conversion" is required from pointer to char to pointer to signed or unsigned char, in all cases they are char.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of storage.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur In your you write "in all cases they are char". That's not correct. They are different types and represents different things. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/436561/4386427 While C may silently allow such conversions that you do, C++ is more strict and require an explicit cast

Comment: @haccks: you are correct, they occupy the same amount of storage which is what I meant when I stated "uses the same amount of space in memory:

Comment: @ScienceAmateur; Yes. Standard also says that *"Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types.*"

Comment: @4386427: I read a number of posts that referred to the "fundamental types" and how there are three types of char.  I'm trying to find what could possibly be the reason to have a third type of char, "plain char", as stated in the documentation.  It seems completely unnecessary and a source of problems.  I'd like to know if there is a good reason for the compiler to consider groups of characters to be "magical" (that is, neither signed nor unsigned).  Would specifying the sign cause problems that I am failing to see ?

Comment: @ScienceAmateur Weel, a "signed char" may not use all bits. It's a historical thing (look up representation of signed number and trap representation). Anyway, I think this starts to be a moving question. The answer to the original question is "Because the types differ". The question in your comment above is more like "Why does the standard define three different char types". To me, that would be another and different answer.

Comment: @4386427: you are correct that inherently I am asking if there is a good reason for the standard to define three different char types.  I presume there must have been a good reason and, I'd certainly like to know what it is.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal: I marked your post as the answer because you provided a way to "convince" the compiler to accept the declaration.  The assembly code generated is as expected,  therefore it solves the problem.  Thank you.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur - Plain char isn't "a third type", it is the *first* type. Originally C only had `char`, and it happened to be signed (because that worked the best on the hardware where it was first implemented). When the C compiler was ported to new hardware, it was more efficient to make `char` unsigned. Who cares, it is only for text? Turned out some people had used `char` as a small integer, and they *did* care. So they were given `signed char` to be able to port their programs. Soon people using the newer machine needed `unsigned char` to move their programs in the other direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile the above code

```
const signed   char * AnArrayOfStrings2[] = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
```

in C with gcc using options `-Wall` then it will give the following warning

```
test.c:5:49: warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
  const unsigned   char * AnArrayOfStrings2[] = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
                                                 ^
test.c:5:49: note: (near initialization for 'AnArrayOfStrings2[0]')
test.c:5:61: warning: pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
  const unsigned   char * AnArrayOfStrings2[] = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
```

The type of elements of `AnArrayOfStrings2` and `"z1y2x3w4"` are different. `AnArrayOfStrings2[0]` is of type `const signed   char *` while `"z1y2x3w4"` is of type `const char[9]`.
The same code will raise error in C++. You will need explicit cast to make it work in C++.

---

To explain why

```
const char * AnArrayOfStrings[]  = {"z1y2x3w4", "Aname"};
```

works I will take s simple example

```
const char c[] = "asc";
const char *p1 = c;           // OK
signed const char *p2 = c;    // Error
unsigned const char *p3 = c;  // Error
```

In the second line of the above snippet, `c` will convert to `const char *` thus making `p1` and `c` compatible types.
In third line the type of `p2` and `c` are incompatible and compiler will raise an error in C++ (a warning in C). Same will happen with line 4.

If we take another example for `int` type

```
const int i[] = {1,2,3};
const int *ii = i            // OK
signed const int *si = i;    // OK
unsigned const int *usi = i; // Error
```

First two pointer initializations work as `int` without any specifier is equivalent to `signed int` (but this is not true with `char`) and therefore types are compatible. Intialization fails in last case as `const int *` or `signed const int *` is incompatible with `unsigned const int *`.

Comment: if the sign is specified the compiler complains that signed (or unsigned) char * is not of type const char[9] yet is perfectly "happy" when the declaration is const char *.  The fact that the programmer intends to interpret the characters as signed or unsigned does not change how the compiler allocates storage for it.  It just seems completely arbitrary for the compiler to complain about the characters being interpreted as signed or unsigned.  Imagine the compiler complaining about an array of signed or unsigned int and force the programmer to only have arrays of int.

Comment: *Imagine the compiler complaining about an array of signed or unsigned int and force the programmer to only have arrays of int* -- except that `int` is actually the same as `signed int`. And it has got nothing to do with the compiler being able to figure out the space etc. It is the semantics of the `=` operator (initialization here) as defined by the standard that prevents this.

Comment: @ScienceAmateur; In fact compiler will complain about assigning any incompatible pointer type.  `int *` and `signed int *` are compatible while these two are incompatible with `unsigned int *`.

Comment: @haccks: I just wanted to let you know that I very much appreciate your providing such a complete explanation along with examples.  I gave the "answered" to Gaurav Sehgal because he provided a way to work around the problem but wanted to make it a point to express my appreciation for your work.  Thank you.