# char and unsigned char different bit operations? || logic OR with char > 0xf0 not working as expected || 0x70 == '\x70' but 0x80 != '\x80'

Tags: c++, string, integer, bit-shift

I think my question boils down to:
Why are `char` and `unsigned Char` treated differently even on bit operations?
They have the same size and look the same

[found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436513/char-signed-char-char-unsigned-char)
but for me it does not explain why it should operate differently on bit operation level

---

I read two bytes from a file.
These have to be be combined into a `16 bit` number.
I do this with *bit shifting* `<<` and *logical or* `|`.

`uint16_t universe = (hb << 8) | lb;`

I thought the code worked fine but sometimes I got weirdly high numbers. `65535` instead of `511`.
It is only happening if `lb` is bigger then `0x80` but the size of `hb` doesn't matter.

So why is `0x70 == '\x70'` but `0x80 != '\x80'` (in some cases)

While writing the question I found that `signed char` and `char` are treated differently if they are `>= 0x80`. (see example below)

Can somebody explain why this is and why it is **even happening while doing bit wise operations**?

And why doesn't it matter with `hb`

**I think the examples explain ist best**

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //different
    uint8_t hb = 0x01;
    uint8_t lb = 0xff;
    uint16_t universe = (hb << 8) | lb;
    cout<<universe << endl; //511
    
    string line = string("\x01\xff");
    universe = (line[0] << 8) | line[1]; 
    cout<<universe << endl; //65535
    
    //different 
    hb = 0x10;
    lb = 0x80;
    universe = (hb << 8) | lb;
    cout<<universe << endl; //4224
    
    line = string("\x10\x80");
    universe = (line.at(0) << 8) | line.at(1);
    cout<<universe << endl; //65408
    
    universe = ('\x10' << 8) | '\x80';
    cout<<universe << endl; //65408 too 
    
    
    //this is fine
    hb = 0x83;
    lb = 0x70;
    universe = (hb << 8) | lb;
    cout<<universe << endl; //33648
    
    line = string("\x83\x70");
    universe = (line[0] << 8) | line[1];
    cout<<universe << endl; //33648
    
    
    //so it is only happening if lower byte is > 0x80
    
    if(0x70 == '\x70')
        cout << "same 0x70" << endl; //same
        
    unsigned char nn = '\x80';
    if(0x80 == nn)
        cout << "now its same 0x80 again " << endl; //same
    
    uint8_t n = '\x80';
    if(0x80 == n)
        cout << "now its same 0x80 again " << endl; //same
    
    if(0x80 == '\x80')
        cout << "not same 0x80" << endl; //actually not the same ?? 
        
    if(nn == '\x80')
        cout << "not same 0x80" << endl; //actually not the same ?? 
        
    char nnn = '\x80';
    if(nnn == '\x80')
        cout << "same 0x80" << endl; //same I THINK THIS IS THE DIFFERENCE
        
    out << sizeof(nn) << sizeof(n) << sizeof(lb)<< sizeof(lb)<<endl; //1 1 1 1
    
    
    //AND WHY IS THIS WORKING ? here is a value  > 0x80  used but its working fine
    hb = 0x90;
    lb = 0x70;
    universe = (hb << 8) | lb;
    cout<<universe << endl; //36976
    
    line = string("\x90\x70");
    universe = (line[0] << 8) | line[1];
    cout<<universe << endl; //36976
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

I fixed it in my code by doing assigning the chars to a `uint8_t`. But I don't understand why it's happening. Why are `char`and `unsigned Char`treaded differently on bit operations?

```cpp
string line = string("\x01\xff");
uint8_t hb = line[0];
uint8_t lb = line[1];

universe = (hb << 8) | lb; 
cout<<universe << endl; //511 like expected
```

Comment: On many systems, apparently including yours, `char` is a signed type.  I'm sure there's a duplicate question about this somewhere on the site.

Comment: Why the C++ code is tagged C?

Comment: @NateEldredge I linked one but I don't get it why the bit operations a differently. both have the same size. or does the system do some weird bit flips even if a sign a hex value

Comment: @273K slipped in - removed it

Comment: It's not really that complicated.  If char is signed, then when `'\x7f'` is used in a 16-bit computation, it has the value `0x007f`.  When `\x80` is used in a 16-bit computation, it has the value `0xff80`.

Comment: Recall that when you apply an arithmetic operator to two values, at least one of which has type smaller than `int`, then both sides are promoted to `int`.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules If `char` is signed 8-bit, then `'\x80'` has numerical value -128, and is promoted to the `int` with value -128 (sign extension).  Whereas `0x80` has numerical value 128.  Then `0x80 == '\x80'` compares the int 128 to the int -128, and indeed they are unequal.

Comment: @TimRoberts but I don't get why the las example is working? (big code section) there is also a value bigger then `'\x7f'`

Comment: @NateEldredge but why is the las example working?

Comment: @Alex *"I don't get why the las example is working?"* -- because your result is `unit16_t`, so there are no higher-order bits than what `line[0]` is supposed to supply. Try changing `universe` to be `uint32_t` (probably `unsigned` would also make the last case fail).

Comment: Your final example is wrong.  The result is not 65535, it is 511.  I just compiled it.  Since all the components are unsigned, there's no sign extension.

Comment: @Tim Roberts change it - just forgot to remove/change the comment. But its working like expected